# execl off by two bytes

Tags: linux, exec, execl

I have this code:

```
    execl("/bin/ip", "address", "add", 
        "dev", ob->tun_name,  
        "local", ob->local_ip,
        "peer", ob->remote_ip,
        NULL
    );
```

But I get the error:

```
Object "dress" is unknown, try "ip help".
```

If I use this:

```
    execl("/bin/ip", "  address", "add", 
        "dev", ob->tun_name,  
        "local", ob->local_ip,
        "peer", ob->remote_ip,
        NULL
    );
```

It works.

I've tried `execlp("ip", ...` but it has the same problem.

What am I doing wrong - why do I need to throw away two characters in front of "address"?

Comment: It sounds like `/bin/ip` has a parsing bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, I needed to add the name of the executable back in.

```
    execl("/bin/ip", "/bin/ip", "address", "add", 
        "dev", ob->tun_name,  
        "local", ob->local_ip,
        "peer", ob->remote_ip,
        NULL
    );
```